# reading from a text file using fscanf()

Tags: c, arrays, struct, scanf

I'm having trouble figuring out what went wrong in my code. I think that my while loop didn't read the file correctly, I was trying to print out the customer name but nothing shows up.

for example, I have a file like this.

```
Smith 3 Sweater $22.50
Reich 3 Umbrella $12.50
Smith 1 Microwave $230.00
Lazlo 1 Mirror $60.00
Flintstone 5 Plate $10.00
Lazlo 1 Fridge $1200.00
Stevenson 2 Chair $350.00
Smith 10 Candle $3.50
Stevenson 1 Table $500.00
Flintstone 5 Bowl $7.00
Stevenson 2 Clock $30.00
Lazlo 3 Vase $40.00
Stevenson 1 Couch $800.00
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct orders_tag {
    int number_of_orders;
    char item_name[20];
    double price;
};

typedef struct orders_tag order;

struct customer_tag {
    char name[30];
    order total_order[100];
};

typedef struct customer_tag customer;

int main(void) {
    FILE *infile;
    customer cus_array[20];
    customer c;
    int customerCounter = 0;

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    infile = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (infile == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't open the fire.");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(infile, "%s %d %s %lf", c.name,  c.total_order[customerCounter].number_of_orders
        , c.total_order[customerCounter].item_name,  c.total_order[customerCounter].price) != EOF) {
        cus_array[customerCounter] = c;
        customerCounter++;
    }

    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < customerCounter; j++) {
        printf("%s", cus_array[j].name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to using `&` for the `int` and `double`, suggest: instead of comparing the `fscanf(...) != EOF)`, use `fscanf(...) == 4)`.  This will terminate the loop on a scan problem rather than getting stuck in an infinite loop.  IOW, use the data when code gets _all_ its inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got many problems in your code.

**Point 1 :** You have to supply the *address* [pointer] to `fscanf()` to store the value. Change

```
while (fscanf(infile, "%s %d %s %lf", c.name,  c.total_order[customerCounter].number_of_orders
    , c.total_order[customerCounter].item_name,  c.total_order[customerCounter].price) != EOF) {
```

to

```
while (fscanf(infile, "%s %d %s %lf", c.name,  &c.total_order[customerCounter].number_of_orders
    , c.total_order[customerCounter].item_name,  &c.total_order[customerCounter].price) != EOF) {
```

**Point 2 :** In your input file, the input in each line is

> Smith 3 Sweater $22.50

so, you've to change your `fscanf()` format to `"%s %d %s $%lf"` to match the input. That's why, it's always advisable to check the rerun value of `fscanf()` and family to ensure proper scanning of all the values.

**Point 3 :** The `customerCounter` variable usage is wrong.

**Point 4 :** As per your input file, `total_order` need not be an array.

Check the below code. It works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct orders_tag {
        int number_of_orders;
        char item_name[20];
        double price;
};

typedef struct orders_tag order;

struct customer_tag {
        char name[30];
        order total_order;   //array not required
};

typedef struct customer_tag customer;

int main(void) {
        FILE *infile;
        customer cus_array[20];
        customer c;
        int customerCounter = 0;

        setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

        infile = fopen("input.txt", "r");

        if (infile == NULL) {
                printf("Couldn't open the fire.");
                return 1;
        }

        while (fscanf(infile, "%s %d %s $%lf", c.name,  &c.total_order.number_of_orders
                                , c.total_order.item_name,  &c.total_order.price) != EOF) {//notice the changes here
                cus_array[customerCounter] = c;
                customerCounter++;
                if (customerCounter == 20) break; // memory allocated for only 20 elements
        }

        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < customerCounter ; j++) {
                printf("Customer :%10s, Number of order : %2d, Item : %10s, Price : $%f\n",
                        cus_array[j].name, cus_array[j].total_order.number_of_orders,cus_array[j].total_order.item_name, cus_array[j].total_order.price);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: weird, It still doesn't print out the name of customer.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what I did wrong, I was busy the whole day until now. Very well explained, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, the line `cus_array[customerCounter] = c;` will not do what you intend. The assignment is a shallow copy operator, so the array fields won't be copied right. Instead you should copy the fields explicitly using `strcpy` and/or `memcpy`. But a better solution would be to work with pointers to the structures rather than structures themselves.

Comment: does that mean I have to make more temp variables and then initialize the struct from there? Thanks.

Comment: I would say the opposite. Get rid of `c` and work directly with array elements. Or make `c` of type `customer*`, assign `&cus_array[customerCounter]` to it, and then read your data into `c->whatever`.